# Replacing %uXXXX to the corresponding Unicode codepoint in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, escaping, gsub

I have filenames which contain %uXXXX substrings, where XXXX are hexadecimal numbers / digits, for example %u0151, etc. I got these filenames by applying URI.unescape, which was able to replace %XX substrings to the corresponding characters but %uXXXX substrings remained untouched. I would like to replace them with the corresponding Unicode codepoints applying String#gsub. I tried the following, but no success:

```
"rep%u00fcl%u0151".gsub(/%u([0-9a-fA-F]{4,4})/,'\u\1')
```

I get this:

```
"rep\\u00fcl\\u0151"
```

Instead of this:

```
"repülő"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
string.gsub(/%u([0-9A-F]{4})/i){[$1.hex].pack("U")}
```

In the comments, [cremno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4231385/cremno) has a better faster solution:

```
string.gsub(/%u([0-9A-F]{4})/i){$1.hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)}
```

In the comments, [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) adds important restrictions, worth reading in full.

Comment: `.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)` instead of `.pack("U")` (and creating an array each time) also works.

Comment: @cremno your answer is better than mine -- if you want to answer, I'll delete mine so you get the check.

Comment: You don't have to delete yours. By the way, `Integer#chr` validates the codepoint (like `\u`), but `Array#pack` doesn't.

Comment: Note this will only work for characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane. A character above U+00FFFF would be encoded as two surrogate `%u` escapes in the range 0xD800–0xDFFF. Also you would need to do the `%nn` decode at the same time as this decode otherwise a literal percent-u sequence would get double-decoded. In this escaping scheme `%nn` sequences are based on ISO-8859-1 bytes not UTF-8. `%u` escapes originally come from the JavaScript `escape` function and are a pretty terrible encoding scheme that is a real pain to deal with correctly. Best avoided if possible.

Comment: @bobince Excellent points. I'm editing the answer to direct readers to your comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Per commenter @cremno's idea, try also this code:

```ruby
gsub(/%u([0-9A-F]{4})/i) { $1.hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) }
```

For example:

```ruby
s = "rep%u00fcl%u0151"
s.gsub(/%u([0-9A-F]{4})/i) { $1.hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) }
# => "repülő"
```